# Using Haskell's "Maybe", type declarations

Tags: haskell, option-type, type-signature

I've started experimenting with Haskell and have a problem. qqq is a function that should print one string if called with "Nothing" and print other things if called with "Just something".

The first attempt seems like working:

```
qqq Nothing = print "There isn't anything to be printed."
qqq (Just x) = print "There is something to be printed." >> print x

main :: IO ()
main = qqq (Just 43)
```

But:

- when I try to make `main = qqq (Nothing)` it fails ("Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint: (Show a0) arising from a use of 'qqq'")
- When I want to add type signature if fails:
- - `qqq :: Maybe x => x -> IO ()` -> `Type constructor 'Maybe' used as a class` -> But isn't it?
- - `qqq :: (Maybe x) -> IO ()`. Now the signature itself looks like succeed. But `main = qqq (Just 43)` starts failing with that mysterious `(Show a0)` error like in `main = qqq (Nothing)` case.

Questions:

1. Why calling qqq with `Nothing` is so different than calling with `Just 43`?
2. What is `(Show a0)`? It is mentioned only in error messages. Any attempts to use it lead to something like "Show not in the scope".
3. What is correct type signature for this? How to make Haskell print type signature it deduced? Expecting something like:

```
f 0 = 2
f x = (f (x-1)) + 3

main = print get_type_as_string(f)
-- prints "Number -> Number"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The type of `qqq` is:

```
qqq :: Show a => Maybe a -> IO ()
```

That means that `qqq` takes one parameter of type `Maybe a` and returns an IO action without a value, with *the constraint* that `a` implements the `Show` typeclass. To find out what `Show` is, you can use `:i Show` in ghci.

`Show` is a typeclass which requires that a value of the type can be converted to a string. `qqq` has the constraint because `print` wants to print out the value (`print` has type `Show a => a -> IO ()`). `Maybe` is not a typeclass but a data type. You can read more about typeclasses [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses).

You can let GHC deduce the type signature either by typing the function in a .hs file, then loading the file with ghci (`ghci Myfile.hs`), and then typing `:t qqq` for displaying the type. You can also define the function in the interactive session with `let qqq n = case n of { Nothing -> print "abc"; Just x -> print "def" >> print x }` (it looks a bit different because the function definition has to be on one line in ghci, but the meaning is the same).

When main calls `qqq` with `qqq (Just 43)`, it is clear the concrete type of `Maybe a` is a numeric type (ghci defaults to Integer), so `qqq` has the concrete type of `Maybe Integer -> IO ()`. However, main calls `qqq` with `qqq Nothing`, `a` could be anything (it is ambiguous) and ghci reports an error.

Comment: Also answered the non-asked question "Why I can't set anything in ghci, it complains `parse error on '='`"

Comment: Is "ambiguous type" always a fail in Haskell or it can decide "the type does matter here, so let it be ambiguous" sometimes?

Comment: Haskell complains of ambiguous types when the compiler doesn't know what to do. So if the compiler can find out what the type will be there's no problem, but if the type must be inferred without enough information about it you get the error.

Comment: The GHC extension ExtendedTypeDefaulting will sometimes allow ghc to choose a default type instead of reporting the ambiguous type error.

Comment: Note that you don't have to rewrite qqq in terms of `case` to make it work in ghci. All you need is to add a `let` at the beginning and replace line breaks with `;` like this: `let qqq Nothing = print "..."; qqq (Just x) = print "..." >> print x`