# How do I properly invoke GI.Gtk scrolledWindowNew in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, gtk3

The [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.18/docs/GI-Gtk-Objects-ScrolledWindow.html#g:20) says:

> Usually you want to pass Nothing for the adjustments

but

```
scrolled <- scrolledWindowNew Nothing Nothing
```

gives me the following error, probably caused by incorrect imports.

```
• Overlapping instances for GI.Gtk.Objects.Adjustment.IsAdjustment
                              a0
    arising from a use of ‘scrolledWindowNew’   Matching instances:
    instance [overlappable] (Data.GI.Base.BasicTypes.GObject a,
                             Data.GI.Base.Overloading.UnknownAncestorError
                               GI.Gtk.Objects.Adjustment.Adjustment a) =>
                            GI.Gtk.Objects.Adjustment.IsAdjustment a
      -- Defined in ‘GI.Gtk.Objects.Adjustment’
    ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
```

my imports look like this

```
import qualified GI.Gtk as GI (init,
                               main)
import GI.Gtk (mainQuit,
               onWidgetDestroy,
               windowNew,
               widgetShowAll,
               containerSetBorderWidth,
               headerBarNew, headerBarSetTitle, headerBarSetSubtitle,headerBarSetShowCloseButton,
               scrolledWindowNew
               )

import GI.Gtk.Objects.Window
import GI.Gtk.Enums
```

### a possible solution

Is it an error in the documentation? Using noAdjustment instead of Nothing seems to work.

```
import qualified GI.Gtk as GI (init,
                               main)
import GI.Gtk (mainQuit,
               onWidgetDestroy,
               windowNew,
               widgetShowAll,
               containerSetBorderWidth,
               headerBarNew, headerBarSetTitle, headerBarSetSubtitle,headerBarSetShowCloseButton,
               scrolledWindowNew, scrolledWindowSetPolicy
               )

import GI.Gtk.Objects.Window
import GI.Gtk.Objects.Adjustment (noAdjustment)

import GI.Gtk.Enums (WindowType(..), PolicyType(..))



  scrolled <- scrolledWindowNew noAdjustment noAdjustment
  scrolledWindowSetPolicy scrolled PolicyTypeNever PolicyTypeAutomatic
```

Inspiration found in Leksah source code.

### please comment

I was trying to translate into Haskell a Python example found here:
http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout.html#flowbox

Working version, with the problem solved, can be found here:
https://github.com/bigos/my-haskell-gtk-3-tutorial/blob/master/5-layout-containers/6-flow-box.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the signature of Data [GI.Gtk.Objects.ScrolledWindow.scrolledWindowNew](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.19/docs/GI-Gtk-Objects-ScrolledWindow.html#v:scrolledWindowNew):

```
scrolledWindowNew :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO m, IsAdjustment a, IsAdjustment b)  =>
                     Maybe a ->
                     Maybe b ->
                     m ScrolledWindow
```

And if you call it like you did

```
scrolled <- scrolledWindowNew Nothing Nothing
```

The compiler knows two things about the (for example) first parameter. It has the type `Maybe a` and about `a` it know, that it is some type with an instance for `IsAdjustment`.

But the compiler needs to know exactly, what the type `a` is and the error message is due to the fact, that it can't deduce it. (Sadly it is pretty weird and not very helpful, as those overlapping instances thingy is intervenes.)

Let's look at, why `noAdjustment` works. If we look up it's documentation [GI.Gtk.Objects.Adjustment.noAdjustment](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.19/docs/GI-Gtk-Objects-Adjustment.html#v:noAdjustment) it type signature reads:

```
noAdjustment :: Maybe Adjustment
```

and the docs state:

> A convenience alias for `Nothing :: Maybe Adjustment`.

And `Adjustment` is a concrete type, which happens to have an instance for `IsAdjustment`.

So the compiler is happy, as it now knows the exact type of the parameters.

Also see

[What is the type of Nothing in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22065358/what-is-the-type-of-nothing-in-haskell)

or

[Using Haskell's "Maybe", type declarations [beginner's question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716330/using-haskells-maybe-type-declarations-beginners-question)

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer. "What is the type of Nothing in Haskell?" was particularly enlightening for me.